# Can test purchases be cancelled in google wallet

Tags: android, android-pay

Previously, using Google Checkout, I was able to make and cancel test in-app purchases made from my Android app using in-app purchasing. Since Google checkout was closed and migrated to Google Wallet, I cannot cancel test purchases. If I view a recent test purchase, the refund button is greyed out.

Does anybody know if and how such purchases may be cancelled in Google Wallet?

This refers to in-app purchases made using a Google play account registered as a test account in my Developer Console settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can.

Go to your orders page, select one of them and in the upper right corner there's a "Refund" button.

Edit: Don't know why it's greyed in your case, I could with no problem.
Give it a couple hours.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: It's been greyed out for a couple of days :( It might be because the test purchase was made just before the switch over to wallet. It should expire on the 30th, so I'll wait until then. After it has expired, I'll be able to make a new test purchase and see if the refund option is enabled.

Comment: @RobinHames - there are quite a few things going on with the _new Merchant Center_ (assuming that's what you're referring to)...and you're right, it seems connected to the sunset of GCO...I can't even get to my _sandbox_ new merchant center at this time....though my sandbox app still works..so it seems confined to Merchant Center. Send them a support email (I did) and they confirmed what I was seeing - your issue is different so you'll help them if you report it too (take screenshots).

Comment: Seems to have been a glitch in the move from checkout to the new Merchant Center. I've been able to cancel new test purchases